# How to use jquery ui autocomplete only feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am integrating autocomplete of jquery in my proeject, and also using jquery malsup form plugin.

Now when i include both of them, none works, which i think is due to conflicts.

How do i use bare minimum jquery autocomplete without any additional css ?

Comment: Malsup form plugin? Can you please at least provide a link so we know what you're using? And basically it's likely this particular plugin that breaks it all. jQuery and jQuery UI play nicely together.

Comment: @Nitin Kabra to see exactly where the problem is, open the js console and load the page. Paste the errors you see here.